# What's wrong with this highscore table code?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Yesterday I wrote up some javascript/php to retrieve info from a table named 'users' in a MySQL database. It takes the username and their 'wealth' and ranks them on score. But, the code below shows nothing except the headers. What's wrong with it? Thanks.

```
<div id="board">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="620"><tbody>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Clicks</td>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php

            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');

            if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            } else {

            mysql_select_db("users");
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT username, wealth FROM users ORDER BY wealth DESC LIMIT 10");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
            $username = $row['username'];
            $wealth = $row['wealth']; } 
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $username;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $wealth;?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php               
            mysqli_close($con);            
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You need to echo the rows out in your while loop.

Comment: One issue is that the table rows that would show your query results are outside the fetch loop. But it seems like you'd still at least see the last one.

Comment: Oh, wait, no you wouldn't. You're mixing mysql with mysqli.

Comment: Is that where I've tripped up? @Don'tPanic

Comment: Yeah, I'd fix that first. The other thing with the loop will be easier to fix. But once you've connected with `mysqli_connect`, you have to use all `mysqli` functions rather than `mysql` ones. Depending on your PHP version, those might not even exist, but even in older versions where before they were removed, you can't mix the two.

Comment: See this Q&A: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498216/can-i-mix-mysql-apis-in-php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to echo rows out in your while loop.

```html
<div id="board">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" width="620"><tbody>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Username</td>
                <td>Clicks</td>                  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php

            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost','xxxx','xxxx','xxxx');

            if (!$con) {
            die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
            } else {

            mysql_select_db("users");
            $results = mysql_query("SELECT username, wealth FROM users ORDER BY wealth DESC LIMIT 10");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
               $username = $row['username'];
               $wealth = $row['wealth']; 

               echo "<tr><td>$username</td><td>$wealth</td></tr>";
            }
          
            mysqli_close($con);  

            echo "<script> var results = $results; console.log(results);</script>";          
            ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is all that is outputted: "; } mysqli_close($con); ?>
Username Clicks
$username $wealth

Comment: It actually outputs "$wealth" @DanWeber

Comment: Had an extra closing "}".

Comment: To debug you could assign the array to a javascript variable and output to the console just to make sure you are getting records back from db properly.